# Why are my types not exposed in my npm package?

Tags: typescript, npm

## node-promise-process - npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-promise-process

package.json

```
  "main": "dist/src/index.js",
  "types": "dist/src/index.d.ts",
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "outDir": "dist",
  },
  "include": [ "src", "@types"]
}
```

src/index.ts

```
import sync from './lib/sync';
export * from './types';
export default sync;
```

src/types.ts

```
import { ExecException } from 'child_process';
export type TError = ExecException | null;
export type TSTDOut = string; // | Buffer;
export type TSuccess = TSTDOut;
export type TSuccessOrError = TSuccess | TError;
export type TPromiseResponse = Promise<TSuccess>;
export type TFunc = () => TSuccessOrError | TPromiseResponse;
export type TcmdOrFunc = string | TFunc;
```

## implementation of npm package

**myproject/example.ts**

```
import sync, { TcmdOrFunc } from 'node-promise-process';
```

> Error - TcmdOrFunc has no exported member

Any help appreciated
thanks

Comment: You may need to change tsconfig.json, adding the following to `compilerOptinos` : `"declaration": true`. https://www.staging-typescript.org/tsconfig#declaration

Comment: @koshelev already has it https://github.com/inspiraller/node-promise-process/blob/master/tsconfig.json

Comment: Hm. Installed the package and VSCode picked-up the types. Looking deeper, the file `".\node_modules\node-promise-process\dist\src\types.d.ts"` from NPM does not have the type you are trying to export. The build from github, however, does have it, so i'm guessing that the stale build somehow got published.

Comment: @Ivan Koshelev thankyou very much for this. Thats interesting. I updated my tag and published it. ok will look into trying to resolving the cache. Much appreciated.

Comment: @IvanKoshelev I've updated the version again to 2.0.1 and ensured I've pushed both to master, and tag number and used npm version 2.0.1 then npm publish. I also had to delete the node_modules and yarn.lock folder of the folder I was testing this package because yarn add node-promise-process -D was not giving me fresh update of version number. It works now. Thanks for your help.